# Authenticating Hotmail's certificate and connection security

Tags: certificates, email, privacy, chrome, hsts

I've recently received the following error message from hotmail.com (or live.com) after I have logged in using Chrome browser, consistent using different accounts and computers (regardless of 2FA or incognito mode):

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from bay181.mail.live.com (for example, 
passwords, messages or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Subject: bing.com
Issuer: Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
Expires on: 3 Apr 2017
Current date: 14 Jun 2015
PEM encoded chain: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.
.
.
. 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

bay181.mail.live.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Chrome tried to 
connect to bay181.mail.live.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. 
Either an attacker is trying to pretend to be bay181.mail.live.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has 
interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection 
before any data was exchanged.

You cannot visit bay181.mail.live.com right now because the website uses HSTS. 
Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
```

While I understand this is a result of HSTS implementation and the redirection of http to https might have been 'insecure', I wish to understand the cause of it, as well as any potential and realistic threats that I might have been facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate has since been fixed by `live.com`.

Previously, the error was only shown after login. As the certificate was not expired, I suspect the transition from http to https didn't meet the standards of [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). In any case, I have determined the issue to be consistent across popular browsers and OS, even email accounts. Seems like it's a server side configuration issue with nothing we can do on client's end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cert chain is actually valid, it looks like its for bing.com instead of the *.mail.live.com domains.

I'd be surprised if anything malicious is going on, but more likely a bad DNS entry, poorly configured certs by Microsoft, or potentially just one part of the browser not realizing another part of the browser is redirecting to the configured search page.

You can test this by comparing the cert on the bad page, with the actual bing.com cert. If cert details match up (thumbprints, CAs, issuance/expiry dates, etc.) then it might be reasonable to chalk it up to environmental issues.